# What does “easy-going” mean？

Tags: meaning, differences, american-english, british-english

I am a non-native English learner. And when I was looking up the word *easy-going* in dictionaries, the explanations really confused me. Is the word *easy-going* positive or negative? Some dictionaries say it means *lax*, *negligent* or *careless*, while some say it means *not easily annoyed*, *worried* or *upset*.

Which is correct? Do you think this word means a good quality or approval. Does it mean that the meaning of the word *easy-going* differs depending on the context, or it's a difference between British and American English

> > [*[American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=easy-going&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)*]
> >
> > adj. 1.
> >
> > a. Living without undue worry or concern; calm.
> >
> > b. Lax or negligent; careless.
> >
> > c. Relaxed or informal in attitude or standards:*an easygoing teacher who allowed extra time for assignments.*
> >
> > [*[Merriam-Webster Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/easygoing)*]
> >
> > a : relaxed and casual in style or manner: *an easygoing boss*
> >
> > b : morally lax
> >
> > [[*Collins English Dictionary*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/easy-going)]
> >
> > If you describe someone as easy-going, you mean that they are not easily annoyed, worried, or upset, and you think this is a good quality. [approval]
> >
> > [[*Chambers Dictionary*](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=easy-going&title=21st)]
> >
> > adj. not strict; relaxed, tolerant or placid.

Comment: Why did you leave out the primary definition  from AHD? **a.** *Living without undue worry or concern; calm.* This is misleading information for users and visitors alike.

Comment: I think what really confused me is just definition 1.b&c from AHD ,so I don't pay too much attention to definition 1.a...I'm quite sorry and thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 5):

The word *easygoing* is positive, not negative, in both American and British English. An *easygoing* person is someone who is liked.

[Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/easygoing) has a good definition:

> Relaxed and tolerant in approach or manner.

Synonyms:

> relaxed, even-tempered, placid, mellow, mild, happy-go-lucky, carefree, free and easy, nonchalant, insouciant, imperturbable, amiable, considerate, undemanding, patient, tolerant, lenient, broad-minded, understanding, good-natured, pleasant, agreeable, laid-back, unflappable, Type-B, low-maintenance

The American Heritage Dictionary definition that you posted which states the word is synonymous with *negligent* and *careless* is not quite correct. *Negligent* and *careless* are negative, but *easygoing* is positive. It would be wrong to replace *negligent* and *careless* with *easygoing* in a sentence. For example, the following sentence does not make any sense:

> She had been *easygoing* and had left the door unlocked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I think the definition“1.b : morally lax”from Merriam-Webster Dictionary is also a little negative,does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, "morally lax" is negative. I cannot explain why Merriam-Webster and American Heritage have these peculiar definitions.